# Passar List para ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Resumidamente:
Tenho uma tela com uma `table` populada pela lista abaixo, aonde seleciono a linha através de `checkbox`, preciso passar essa lista para a minha `actionResult`.

Como não tenho um formulario nessa tela não consigo dar submit nos dados para passar para a `actionResult`.

ViewModel usado no html com a propriedade lista

```
    public class DeliveryServiceListViewModel
{
     public List<DeliveryServiceViewModel> DeliveryServices { get; set; }
}
```

`ActionResult`:

```
public ActionResult EditAll()
{
}
```

Que eu chamo dessa maneira que não sei se é a correta:

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EditAll", "DeliveryService")'">
    Salvar
</button>
```

- Como passar a lista para eu tratar no `controller`?
- Tem como eu passar apenas a lista ou eu tenho que passar todo o ViewModel que contem a lista?

Tentei passar a lista usando `new { DeliveryServices = Model.DeliveryServices }`, mas ela chega no `controller` vazia.

```
 @model Dlieve.BackOffice.Areas.BackOffice.Models.DeliveryServiceListViewModel

 <table class="table-long" id="deliveries">
    <tr>
        <th>Portador</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Data de Cadastro</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Motivo Entrega Não Realizada</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckBoxes" /></th>
        <th colspan="4">
            <div class="btnSituacao" hidden>
                <button onclick="enviarFormulario()">Salvar</button>
                <button id="cancel">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th></th>
    @if (Model != null)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Model.DeliveryServices.Count; i++)
        {
            var checkboxChecked = Model.DeliveryServices[i].IsSelected;

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => carrierFullName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => shipperCustomerFullName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].Created)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].DeliveryServiceStatusModel.Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].NonDeliveryDescription)</td>

                @*declaração de variavel local para simplificar o tratamento condicional de "description"*@
                @{var description = Model.DeliveryServices[i].DeliveryServiceStatusModel.Description;}
                @if (description == "Em Andamento" || description == "Roteirizado")
                {
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].IsSelected)</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td></td>
                }
                        }
                    }

</table>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa. Um botão `submit` tendo um `Javascript` sem sentido no meu entender, parece ser o problema.

Comment: retirei o submit, o botão chama a `ActionResult` porem não sei passar a minha lista como parâmetro.

Comment: poste o seu `form` completo....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto não dispara um `POST`:

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("EditAll", "DeliveryService")'">
    Salvar
</button>
```

Aliás, não entendi qual o objetivo de usar o `button` assim. De qualquer forma, se você realmente precisa que o JavaScript faça o `POST` pra você, terá que mudar para:

```
<button onclick="enviarFormulario()">
    Salvar
</button>
```

E depois:

```
function enviarFormulario()
{
    $.post("@Url.Action("EditAll", "DeliveryService")", { campo1: $('#campo1'), campo2: $('#campo2'), campo3: $('#campo3') }, function(result) {
        // Faça alguma coisa aqui com result
    });
}
```

Esse exemplo [usa jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

---

**EDIT**

A ideia é o seguinte:

```
function enviarFormulario()
{
    var lista = [];
    $(":checkbox").each(function(index) {
        lista.push({ "Campo1DoDeliveryServiceViewModel": "Valor1",
                     "Campo2DoDeliveryServiceViewModel": "Valor2",
                     "Campo3DoDeliveryServiceViewModel": "Valor3" });
    });

    $.post("@Url.Action("EditAll", "DeliveryService")", lista, function(result) {
        // Faça alguma coisa aqui com result
    });
}
```

Acredito que você queira mandar o valor das `checkboxes` para o *Controller*. Possivelmente será necessário preencher alguma coisa com o Id e o respectivo valor da `checkbox`.

Comment: Na verdade não preciso que ele faça para min, editei minha pergunta acho que ficou mais clara. O que eu não sei fazer é pegar a lista que popula minha `table` e passar para a `actionResult`.

Comment: Pois então. Isso não muda em nada o conteúdo da minha resposta. Implemente os passos que coloquei e verá a lista ser materializada corretamente no *Controller*.

Comment: fiz do modo que você falou e a chamada deu certo ele bate na `actionResult`, porem a minha lista, que popula a minha `<table>`, que é um propriedade da minha ViewModel, eu não sei passar pelo `$.post`

Comment: É, então. Você terá que construir o objeto usando JavaScript. Editando sua pergunta e colocando o HTML/Razor da `<table>`, posso montar algo pra você.

Comment: entendi, editei colocando o código da `<table>`

Comment: @Vinicius Veja se ficou mais claro agora.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53133/discussion-between-vinicius-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema pelo visto é porque você não está dando o submit no form e sim simplesmente redirecionando para a action no click do botão. Com isso as informações não serão passadas para a controller porque o post não está sendo feito, por isso sua lista chega nula.

Comment: Você tem razão, Editei a minha pergunta.