# Passar propriedades do ViewModel para o Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

coloquei minha table dentro de um `BeginForm` passando meu controller e minha action, porem quando dou submit os campos estão NULL no controller, acho que não esta passando as propriedades do ViewModel.

```
@model Dlieve.BackOffice.Areas.BackOffice.Models.DeliveryServiceListViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditAll", "DeliveryService", FormMethod.Post))
{

<table class="table-long" id="deliveries">
    <tr>
        <th>Portador</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Data de Cadastro</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Motivo Entrega Não Realizada</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectAllCheckBoxes" /></th>
        <th colspan="4">
            <div class="btnSituacao" hidden>
                <input type="submit" value="@Resources.ViewLabelNameStrings.Save" />
                <button id="cancel">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
            <select id="situacao" disabled>
                <option selected disabled hidden>Alterar Status</option>
                <option value="realizada">Realizada</option>
                <option value="naoRealizada">Não Realizada</option>
            </select>
        </th>
        <th></th>

        @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserPermission.DeliveryServiceEdit))
            {
            <th></th>
        }

        @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserPermission.DeliveryServiceEdit))
            {
            <th></th>
        }

        @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserPermission.DeliveryServiceDelete))
            {
            <th></th>
        }
    </tr>
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var deliveries in Model.DeliveryServices)
            {
                var checkboxChecked = deliveries.IsSelected;

                var carrierFullName = "Não Definido";
                if (deliveries.CarrierModel != null)
                {
                    carrierFullName = String.Concat(deliveries.CarrierModel.FirstName, " ", deliveries.CarrierModel.LastName);
                }

                var shipperCustomerFullName = "Não Definido";
                if (deliveries.ShipperCustomerModel != null)
                {
                    shipperCustomerFullName = deliveries.ShipperCustomerModel.CompanyName ?? String.Concat(deliveries.ShipperCustomerModel.FirstName, " ", deliveries.ShipperCustomerModel.LastName);
                }

                if (ViewBag.Routes.ContainsKey("id"))
                {
                    ViewBag.Routes.Remove("id");
                }
                ViewBag.Routes.Add("id", deliveries.IdDeliveryService);

                Html.RenderPartial("_DeliveryServiceEntry.cshtml", deliveries);
            }
            }
        </tbody>
    }
</table>

    <div id="IdCarrierDiv" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="IdShipperCustomerDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

}

**Minha partial:**

```
@model Dlieve.BackOffice.Areas.BackOffice.Models.DeliveryServiceListViewModel

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("DeliveryServices"))
{
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => carrierFullName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => shipperCustomerFullName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => deliveries.Created)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => deliveries.Description)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => deliveries.DeliveryServiceStatusModel.Description)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => deliveries.NonDeliveryDescription)</td>

    @*declaração de variavel local para simplificar o tratamento condicional de "description"*@
    @{var description = deliveries.DeliveryServiceStatusModel.Description;}
    @if (description == "Em Andamento" || description == "Roteirizado")
    {
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => deliveries.IsSelected)</td>
    }
    else
    {
        <td></td>
    }
    <td class="table-comand">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", ViewBag.Routes)" title="Detalhes" class="table-details-link"></a>
    </td>

    @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserPermission.DeliveryServiceEdit))
    {
        <td class="table-comand">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", ViewBag.Routes)" title="Editar" class="table-edit-link"></a>
        </td>
    }

    @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserPermission.DeliveryServiceEdit))
    {
        <td class="table-comand">
            @if (deliveries.IdDeliveryServiceStatus == (int)Dlieve.Model.Enums.DeliveryServiceStatusEnum.Cancelado)
                {
                <a title="Entrega/Serviço cancelado" class="table-block-disabled"></a>
            }
            else
            {
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-cancel-delivery="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => deliveries.IdDeliveryService)" title="Cancelar" class="table-block-link"></a>
            }
        </td>
    }

    @if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserPermission.DeliveryServiceDelete))
    {
        <td class="table-comand">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", ViewBag.Routes)" title="Excluir" class="table-delete-link"></a>
        </td>
    }
</tr>
```

}

meu ViewModel:

```
public class DeliveryServiceListViewModel
{
    public string CarrierFullName { get; set; }
    public string ShipperCustomerFullName { get; set; }

    //public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DeliveryServiceViewModel> DeliveryServices { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<long, string> DeliveryServiceTypes { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<long, string> DeliveryServiceStatus { get; set; }
}
```

minha action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditAll(DeliveryServiceListViewModel model)
    {}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro no Partial:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
o `public IList<DeliveryServiceViewModel> DeliveryServices` é a lista que popula a `<table>` e que eu gostaria de passar para o controller

Comment: eu precisava que as propriedades do ViewModel fossem para a lista, mais especificamente a lista `DeliveryServices` que aparece na imagem, ela contem os campos que preciso.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181996/passar-list-para-actionresult

Answer (score 2):

Agora já é um caso de usar o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/). [Tem várias respostas a respeito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=begincollectionitem), mas vou passar também alguns passos que podem ser úteis.

### 1. Coloque isto numa Partial, por exemplo, `_DeliveryServiceEntry.cshtml`

```
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => carrierFullName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => shipperCustomerFullName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].Created)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].DeliveryServiceStatusModel.Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].NonDeliveryDescription)</td>

                @*declaração de variavel local para simplificar o tratamento condicional de "description"*@
                @{var description = Model.DeliveryServices[i].DeliveryServiceStatusModel.Description;}
                @if (description == "Em Andamento" || description == "Roteirizado")
                {
                    @*<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.DeliveryServices[i].IsSelected)</td>*@
                    <td>
                        <input id="DeliveryServices_@(i)__IsSelected" name="DeliveryServices[@i].IsSelected" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="@checkboxChecked">
                        <input id="DeliveryServices_@(i)__IdDeliveryService" name="DeliveryServices[@i].IdDeliveryService" type="hidden" value="@Model.DeliveryServices[i].IdDeliveryService">
                    </td>

                }
                else
                {
                    <td></td>
                }
                }
            </tr>
```

### 2. Use o `Html.BeginForm` normal, sem *ViewBags*

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditAll", "DeliveryService", FormMethod.Post)) { ... }
```

Comment: editei minha pergunta com o partial mas por algum motivo não consigo instalar o `beginCollectionItem` usando `Install-Package BeginCollectionItem` me retorna esse erro:

`Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'BeginCollectionItem' from source 'nuget.org'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package BeginCollectionItem
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
 `

Comment: Seu NuGet não está atualizado, está?

Comment: acho que consegui instalar, editei minha pergunta com a partial e o viewModel, porem me retorna um erro queb tambem coloquei na minha pergunta, nas outras perguntas que você respondeu sobre o BeginCollectionItem os ViewModel com um `List` esyão parecidos com o  meu.

Comment: Verifique se tem uma entrada em `<namespaces>` para o `BeginCollectionItem` no arquivo `Web.config` **dentro do diretório `Views`** (não o `Web.config` do diretório raiz). Verifique também se o pacote está mesmo instalado corretamente através do Object Explorer.